# Unreal Engine Gravity, AddImpulse & Physics

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

Hey guys I wanted to know if the physics in unreal engine aka gravity, Addimpulse are frame rate dependent meaning the output will be affected by the machine's current FPS in-game. if that is the case how can I make a Ball fall down on every machine equally how to use Getworlddeltaseconds with gravity or Addimpulse will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is a little context-dependent question. By default physics updates every frame so yes, it is framerate-dependent, but at the same time it takes into count time between updates so in most cases that dependency is not noticable.

However, if you still need more acurate and determinable physics you may want to tweak physics sub-stepping parameters ([documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/InteractiveExperiences/Physics/Substepping/)) to achieve what you need. What this feature basically does is it forces engine to call additional physics updates between rendering ticks once every time interval. Be careful tough as if your simulation takes longer to process then defined time interval whole physics update sequence may break.

Hope that answers your question.